# Oracle Apex sorting interactive grid

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

it is possible to use static LOV (default, newest, latest) to sort interactive grid by date column? I tried to use `order by` in query, but it's not allowed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually, you can:

Open the Oracle APEX Builder and make sure you are logged in as developer run the Page with the Interactive Grid in the browser and log in with the same credentials
Apply an order by on one (or more) of the columns
Click 'Actions' -> 'Report'-> 'Save'
You should see the confirmation "Default report saved for all users"
Have you tried using a view with order by and then doing a select query?

WITH my_sel AS
(SELECT emp_id, name, date
FROM employees
ORDER BY date DESC)

SELECT emp_id, name, date
FROM my_sel;

Answer (score 0):

As far as **I** can tell (which means that someone might know better), you can't do that because interactive grid's `select` statement doesn't support `order by` clause; if you try to add it, you'd get

> ORDER BY clause is not supported, use column sorting instead.

which means that - once you run the report - navigate to "Actions" menu, go to "Data" and choose the "Sort" option.

Can that help in what you're trying to do? Perhaps! How? By **saving the custom report**. So:

- sort data any way you want
- go to "Actions > Report > Save as", give it a name and save it
- repeat these steps as many times as you want
- when you're done, you'll see new option in the toolbar which will let users pick report they want, without having to manually sort data themselves. Something like this (a simple interactive grid based on Scott's `emp` table):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i'm looking for

Comment: I know; that would be a *workaround* if you can't do it the way you'd want it to.